# Google App Script: Auto Refresh after form submission

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have an app script gadget embedded in a google site. What the app script does is get objects from scriptdb and display it on the screen. There also is an add button clicking on which you get a form to enter information and add objects. What I am trying to do is that after an object is saved, I repopulate the object and display them so the newly created object can be seen without manually refreshing the page.

I have a function called `update()` that is called after an object is saved and this function takes care of the "auto refresh".

In the `save()` function, I call the update function with this syntax, `update()`. Here is the `submit()` function

```
function SaveAssignment(e){
    var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   var name = e.parameter.assignmentname;
   var date = e.parameter.assignmentdate.toString();
   var desc = e.parameter.assignmentdesc;
   var category = e.parameter.assignmentcategory;
   var totalscore = e.parameter.assignmenttotalscore;

   var site = SitesApp.getActiveSite();

   var assignment = { name: name,
                date: date,
                description: desc,
                url: pageUrl + '?name='+name+'&date='+date+'&description='+desc+'&id='+sheetId,
                sheetid: sheetId,
                totalScore: totalscore,
                Category: category
               };

  db.save(assignment);

  update();
}
```

and here is my `update()` method

```
function update(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var oldGrid = app.getElementById('grid');
  app.remove(oldGrid);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('AddAssignment');

  var addAssignmentButton = app.createButton('Add Assignment', handler);

  var assignments = db.query({});
  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;

  var grid; 
  if(assignments.getSize() < 1){
    grid =  app.createGrid(3, 5).setId('grid');
  }
  else{
   grid = app.createGrid(assignments.getSize() + assignments.getSize() + assignments.getSize(), 5).setId('grid');
  }
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  grid.setWidget(0, 2, addAssignmentButton);

  while(assignments.hasNext()){
    var assignment = assignments.next();
    var name = assignment.name;
    var date = assignment.date;
    var description = assignment.description;

    var nameLabel = app.createLabel('Assignment ' + i + ' : ' + name).setVisible(true);
    var dateLabel = app.createLabel('Date: ' + date).setVisible(true);
    var idLabel = app.createLabel(assignment.getId()).setVisible(false);
    var deletebutton = app.createButton('Delete Assignment');
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('deleteAssignment');

   handler.addCallbackElement(idLabel);
   deletebutton.addClickHandler(handler);

   grid.setWidget(j, 0, nameLabel);
   j = j + 1;
   grid.setWidget(j, 0, dateLabel);
   grid.setWidget(j, 1, deletebutton);
   grid.setWidget(j, 3, idLabel);

    i++;
    j = j + 2;
 }
 app.add(grid);
 return app;
```

Comment: not sure if the rest of the code work but change the "var app = UiApp.createApplication();" for "var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication()".

Comment: Makes sense, I changed it but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some little test on your code. you need to do some little changes:
You need to change  "var app = UiApp.createApplication();" for "var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication()" (already saw that in comment).
You didn't declared "db" your script will systematically be in error if you don't correct that.

Bellow your code where the update function actually update the grid:

```
function doGet(){
 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 3).setId("grid").setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel("test"));
  grid.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("update"));
  app.add(grid);
  return(app);
}

function update(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); // getActiveApplication

  var oldGrid = app.getElementById('grid');
  app.remove(oldGrid);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('AddAssignment');
  var addAssignmentButton = app.createButton('Add Assignment', handler);
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var assignments = db.query({}); // YOU DIDNT DECLARED db

  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;
  var grid; 
  if(assignments.getSize() < 1){
    grid =  app.createGrid(3, 5).setId('grid');
  }
  else{
   grid = app.createGrid(assignments.getSize() + assignments.getSize() + assignments.getSize(), 5).setId('grid'); // assignments.getSize()*3
  }
  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  grid.setWidget(0, 2, addAssignmentButton);

  while(assignments.hasNext()){
    var assignment = assignments.next();
    var name = assignment.name;
    var date = assignment.date;
    var description = assignment.description;
    var nameLabel = app.createLabel('Assignment ' + i + ' : ' + name).setVisible(true);
    var dateLabel = app.createLabel('Date: ' + date).setVisible(true);
    var idLabel = app.createLabel(assignment.getId()).setVisible(false);
    var deletebutton = app.createButton('Delete Assignment');
    var handler = app.createServerHandler('deleteAssignment');
   handler.addCallbackElement(idLabel);
   deletebutton.addClickHandler(handler);
   grid.setWidget(j, 0, nameLabel);
   j = j + 1;
   grid.setWidget(j, 0, dateLabel);
   grid.setWidget(j, 1, deletebutton);
   grid.setWidget(j, 3, idLabel);
    i++;
    j = j + 2;
 }
 app.add(grid);
 return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this kinda works. I have declare `db` as a global variable so I have that settled. But did you change anything except for `UiApp.getActiveApplication();`? I can't find anything else that is different.

Comment: I added "var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();"

Comment: commented out that line and it still works. Weird. Thanks anyways. Although, the grid seems to be shifting by 1 row everytime the update method is called. Can you think of a reason why this might be happening?