# Google Form auto load survey page after submitting

Tags: forms, submit, survey

I have this form on Google Drive and was wondering would it be possible to go back to the form after the user has submitted/clicked the survey. Currently once the survey has been completed it gives a message to the users saying thank you for your response. My survey is linked with a spreadsheet where it collects all the feedback. Do I need to add some kind of code within the script editor to do this and if so which one? I tried searching for answers and the closest search I have come across is this one:

[Google App Script: Auto Refresh after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674447/google-app-script-auto-refresh-after-form-submission)

I appreciate if anyone could provide help or advice on how to do this.

To simplifer what I want:

1) Have the form completed and submitted. It should then load saying thank you and reload the survey so the next person can complete it without having to click back or refresh the page.

I hope this makes sense to everyone.

Many thanks

Daniel